# jmeter UI is white

Tags: java, centos, jmeter

when I run .jmx from terminal in CentOs (3.10.0-514 gcc 4.8.5-11) jdk - 1.8.0-121-b13), the .jmx executes according to the test plan. However, I cannot get UI. That is, Jmeter starts with jmeter.sh but screen is just white.

[image]

Comment: Are you executing the JMX file using NON-GUI mode?

Comment: If I execute .jmx non-gui it works fine because UI is not required. But for debugging I were trying to load Jmeter UI, the Jmeter UI is just blank.

Comment: Can you please post the jmeter.log message here?

Comment: Naveen- lovded up "JMX file Log Screenshot".

Comment: Thanks. I compared it with mine. You may need to reinstall the JMeter again. Few JAR(S) might be missing in bin folder.

Comment: will try that. thanks

Comment: well actually- i were running rdp w/ 32 b color depth. Later changed to 24 b. It worked.